# Session based DOM object visibility manipulation in real time application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am developing a remote monitoring application and have an issue that I would like to see if I can get some ideas on how best to resolve.

When the server determines there is new information in the database to display to the client, it calls the SignalR client method which requests a new partial view.

On the main page I have a simple JQuery script which toggles visibility of tables, and child rows contained in the partial view.

The problem should be apparent now. When AJAX updates the DOM with a newly returned partial view, the objects in the partial view are returned to their initial default visibility state. This is completely expected, however I would like to make the visibility state of each element persistent throughout the connected client's session.

The data in the partial view largely remains the same (don't really need to worry about tables and or rows being added or deleted as far as the normal real-time operation is concerned.)

The Code:

JQuery controls: (Not optimized, but working)

```
    $("#systemDetails").on("click", "#deviceDetail", function () {
    if ($(this).closest('tr').next().is(':hidden')) {
        $("[id^=child]").hide();
        $("[id^=deviceDetail]").removeClass('glyphicon-minus-sign');
        $("[id^=deviceDetail]").addClass('glyphicon-plus-sign');
        $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-minus-sign");
    }
    else {
        $("[id^=child]").hide();
        $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-minus-sign");
    }
});

$("#systemDetails").on("click", "#categoryToggle", function () {
    $(this).closest('table').next().toggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-minus-sign");
});
```

Main View:

```
    @model xxxx.Models.SystemModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "System Details";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="systemDetails">
            @Html.Action("GetDetails", "Monitoring", Model.Customer.SONumber)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="/Scripts/systemdetails.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var notifications = $.connection.monitoringHub;

        //debugger;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        notifications.client.updateDetails = function (sonumber) {
            getDetails(sonumber)
        };
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            //alert("connection started")
            getDetails(@Model.Customer.SONumber.ToString());
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });

    function getDetails(sonumber) {
        if(sonumber = (@Model.Customer.SONumber.ToString())){
            var tbl = $('#systemDetails');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Monitoring/GetDetails/@Model.Customer.SONumber.ToString()',
                contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false
            }).success(function (result) {
                tbl.empty().append(result);
            }).error(function () {

            });
        }
    }
</script>
}
```

Relevant sample of Partial view: (If there is more code you would like to see, please request it)

```
@foreach (var category in Model.Devices.Select(d => d.Room).Distinct())
{
    <table class="table-borderless">
        <tr>
            <td valign="middle"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lg glyphicon-plus-sign" id="categoryToggle"></i></td>
            <td><h2 class="tableheader">@category</h2></td>

            @if (Model.Devices.Where(d => d.Room == category).Any(d => d.Status == "Offline"))
            {
                <td valign="middle"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lg glyphicon-warning-sign"></i></td>
                <td><h2 class="tableheader">@(Model.Devices.Where(d => d.Room == category && d.Status == "Offline").Count())</h2></td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td valign="middle"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lg glyphicon-ok"></i></td>
            }
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="display:none" class="table">
    (...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possible design paths:

1. **Switch to update data only, not HTML.**  Change the way you update your page so that you update only the data in the page rather than replace the HTML.  This would require a restructure of how you get and apply your update, but would retain all the HTML elements in your page so the visibility state would be retained also.  To do this, you would likely request JSON data from your server which your client code would then fill into the current HTML.  This is obviously more work than what you are doing now, but has the advantage of retaining all DOM state because the DOM elements are not replaced (except for some text nodes).
2. **Save visibility state, then restore that state after updating DOM.**  If you are going to replace the DOM objects with new HTML, then you will need to save the visibility settings from the original DOM and then after replacing with a new section of DOM, you will have to then apply those earlier visibility settings to the new DOM elements.  This would require being able to map an old DOM element to the corresponding new DOM element.  If you know that the table row structure stays identical and you are just showing/hiding rows, then you could literally just create an array of hidden row numbers in your code (e.g. `var hiddenRows = [1,5,6,7,10]`) before you replace the section of DOM, then put in the new HTML, then go hide each of the rows listed in the array.